# Filepath for reading file in library code

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io, lwjgl, bufferedreader

I need to read a glsl source file into my program.

I am writing a library, and have my test code in a separate project in Eclipse.

In the build path for the test project I have set the "Required projects on Build Path" to include the library I am writing.

The issue is that when I run my test project it looks for "src/example/vertexShader.glsl". Java tries to read this from the src folder in the test project, not the library project.

I have copied over the file to the test project and run it, and it works fine, so I know it's looking for the file in the wrong project.

I am using the following code to create a reader to read in the text:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

How can I have it so that it reads specifically from my Library project, even if I run the code via a different project?

Comment: "and have my test code in a separate project in Eclipse" - I'd expect your code and unit tests to be in the same project, code under `src/main/java` and unit tests under `src/test/java`. Why are they in different projects?

Comment: Because the idea is that I will package the Library individually, so I'm writing a separate project to sort of emulate that use case

Comment: Also that wouldn't solve my problem, because when the library is finished and packaged as a jar, a separate project will be referencing it anyway, so this problem will just occur again

Comment: Are you using Maven or similar?

Comment: I'm not using anything like that. I'm just using Java and Eclipse. I have the LWJGL and SlickUtil jars configured in the Project's Build Configuration. I'm going to build the final Library jar using Eclipse's inbuilt export features

Comment: What's included in your jar? Run `jar tf foo.jar`

Comment: I haven't made a jar yet. That's for when I'm done. They're two eclipse projects

Comment: Jar up the main project and include vertexShader.glsl at the root then add that jar to the classpath of the test project.

Comment: I've found the problem. I don't need to do any of that

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse treats my Library project as a project that is already packaged into a Jar from the viewpoint of the test project.
So to load resources from inside the project, which from the viewpoint of the test project, looks like inside of the Jar file, I need to use getResourceAsStream instead of a BufferedReader that uses a File object, as my glsl source file will no longer be a "file".
To fix this, I have to change the previous BufferedReader code to:

```
InputStream in = Class.class.getResourceAsStream(file);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

This fixes the problem and allows me to load resources from inside of the Library project.